# A question about inclusion of $L^r(\mu)$ spaces for different $r$ and different measures $\mu$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

> For some measures, the relation $r<s$ implies $L^r(\mu)\subseteq L^s(\mu)$ ; for others, the inclusion is reversed; and there are some for which $L^r(\mu)$ does not contain $L^s(\mu)$ if $r\ne s$. Give examples of these situations, and find conditions on $\mu$

I am thanked if you give some hint. I do not know how to start to think about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint 1: If you do not have sets of arbitrarily small measure, one of the inclusions $L^r \subset L^s$ holds. For instance, consider $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$. How does this relate to $\left(\int_X |f(x)|^p d\mu(x)\right)^{1/p}$?

Hint 2: If you do not have sets of arbitrarily large measure, the other inclusion holds. For instance, what can you say about $\frac{1}{x}$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ integrated on $[0,1]$?

Hint 3: If you want something to belong to a single $L^p$, you can't have either of the inclusions. That is, you need a space with infinite total measure and sets of arbitrarily small measure, like $[0,\infty)$. You have to do some arts and crafts (gluing) on functions which behave like $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ (which is in $L^1([0,1])$ but not $L^1([1,\infty])$) and $\frac{1}{x^2}$ (which is in $L^1([1,\infty))$ but not $L^1([0,1])$).

Finally, you will need a "tipping" point, which can be achieved by using a function like $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}\log x}$. Notice that this $f \in L^2([0,1])$, but $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \notin L^2([0,1])$.

Answer (score 3):

If $\mu(X)<\infty$, then 
$$
p<q \quad\Longrightarrow\quad L^q(X)\subset L^p(X).
$$
This is due to the fact that (Holder inequality)
$$
\int_X \lvert\, f\rvert^p\,d\mu=\int_X \lvert\, f\rvert^p\cdot 1\,d\mu
=\left(\int_X \lvert\, f\rvert^q\,d\mu\right)^{p/q}
\left(\int_X 1^{q/(q-p)}\,d\mu\right)^{(q-p)/q}.
$$
Hence $\|\,f\|_p\le \mu(X)^{\frac{q-p}{pq}}\|\,f\|_q$.

If $X=\mathbb N$, and $\mu(A)$ is the cardinality of $A$, then
$$
p<q \quad\Longrightarrow\quad L^q(X)\supset L^p(X).
$$
To understand this, note first that $$L^p(\mathbb N)=\big\{(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}: \textstyle\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\lvert a_n\rvert^p<\infty\big\}.$$

Combine the two previous results to get an example where if $p\ne q$, 
then $L^p\not\subset L^q$.

Comment: The general result is that one inclusion is related to the measure being bounded away from infinity, and the other is related to the measure being bounded away from zero (when nonzero).